# How do I make a super class's custom init method only internally visible to its subclasses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I currently have this init method for my superclass:

```
- (id)initWithFoo:(int)foo;
```

In a subclass, I have a custom init method that calls its superclass's init, like this. Bar is exclusive to the subclass.

```
-(id)initWithFoo:(int)foo Bar:(int)bar {
    if (self = [super initWithFoo:foo]){
        _bar = bar;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I run into problems when I create an instance of the subclass, because the compiler happily suggests the superclass init method in the list of possible initialization methods for my subclass instance, which I definitely do not want.

However, if I remove initWithFoo:(int)foo from the superclass's .h file then the subclasses can no longer use it within their own init methods.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: [Related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679885/xcode-now-generates-an-empty-category-why) (although not the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement initWithFoo in your superclass and in your child make an "extension" declaration:

```
@interface SuperClass()
- (instancetype)initWithFoo:(int)foo;
@end
```

Make sure to place that declaration above @implementation in the .m file of your child

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I completely forgot I could do that :)