# Why is there an empty pair of parentheses in interface extensions in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Interface definitions in implementation files look like this:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property ...;

@end
```

While interfaces in the header files have the superclass instead of the parentheses (`@interface MyClass : NSObject`). Why is that? Where does it come from?

Comment: This may be described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679885/. Does it answer your question?

Comment: It's called "Class Extensions". For more information see ["Customizing Existing Classes" in the Programming in Objective-C guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)